# Difference between eq and == in Grails withCriteria query

Tags: grails

I want to fetch from my DB all requirements related to a given project(in this case currentProject)
I've just used two ways to do this

first one :

```
Requirement.withCriteria {....
    eq("project", currentProject)
    ...
}
```

I note that this query doesn't use equals method of Project class, but this query returns me exactly what I want.

second

```
Requirement.withCriteria {
    ....        
    currentProject == property('Project')
    ...
}
```

This query use equals method to compare two projects, but I could not overwrite equals method that a exception has been thrown saying "grails can't cast hibernateBuild to domain"

So, I wonder know what the difference between those two queries ?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withCriteria` method goes to the Database to fetch your entities.

On the database level there is no concept of equals (DB does not know anything about Java). First query gives you the right results because it compares the DB mapping (PRIMARY / FOREIGN keys).

As for the second query - I do not advice to use it. If it uses equals, when it fetches all projects from the DB into memory. And that is a really bad idea.

Comment: think you for your explanation